# Buffon-Laplace Long Needle Probl

Tags: calculus, probability

Firstly, Buffon-Laplace needle problem is a very famous problem in probability that was solved by Laplace in 1812. While researching about this problem, I realized that there is no information about the case where the length of the needle l exceeds the dimensions of the grid.
$l>max(a,b)$ Where a and b are the length and width of the grid respectively.
Why is that so that there is no information at avaiable at all even thought the case of shorter needle was solved in 1812. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: If $l \gt \sqrt {a^2+b^2}$ it is easy.  The chance the needle doesn't hit a grid line is $0$.  When the needle is short you solve the problem with parallel grid lines, double it for the other direction, and worry about the corners.  You don't have the grid lines interacting.

Comment: Have you looked, Dev, at the questions listed on this page as "Related"?

Comment: Yes I have looked at related questions and i am looking at the case where $max(a,b)<l<\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$